# MDCTabBarViewController Get Bar To Top Position

Tags: material-components, material-components-ios

I'm using iOS Material components in my app and I came across the Tabs [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/Tabs). Implementing it was easy and after I made a few minor changes to match my design the result was what I wanted:

[image: Right position tab bar]

I achieved this using the following code:

```
func setupTabBar() {
    let customTabBar = MDCTabBar(frame: view.bounds)
    customTabBar.items = [
        UITabBarItem(title: "Cards", image: nil, tag: 0),
        UITabBarItem(title: "Mobile", image: nil, tag: 0)            
    ]
    customTabBar.itemAppearance = .titledImages
    customTabBar.alignment = .justified
    customTabBar.itemAppearance = .titles

    //colors
    customTabBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
    customTabBar.selectedItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    customTabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    customTabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.33, blue:0.59, alpha:1.0)

    tabBarContainerView.addSubview(customTabBar)
    customTabBar.sizeToFit()

    tabBarContainerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    tabBarContainerView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
    tabBarContainerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    tabBarContainerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor        
}
```

However, this is just the Tar bar, I need to have a functional tab view where the user can switch between the two pages. No problem, as the docs say just inherit from MDCTabBarViewController, this ensure my pages are being tabbed, but this also added another tab bar at the bottom, which is fine, now I do not net to create one myself, so I removed mine but now I would just like it to bo the top but cannot find a property to set to get it in the top position:

[image: wrong position tab bar]

and here is the code for that:

```
func setupTabViews()  {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let cardsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cardsWalletViewController")
    let mobileVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mobileWalletViewController")

    let vcArray = [cardsVC, mobileVC]
    viewControllers = vcArray

    let childVC = viewControllers.first
    selectedViewController = childVC

    tabBar?.delegate = self

    tabBar?.items = [
        UITabBarItem(title: "Cards", image: nil, tag: 0),
        UITabBarItem(title: "Mobile", image: nil, tag: 0)
    ]

    tabBar?.itemAppearance = .titledImages
    tabBar?.alignment = .justified
    tabBar?.itemAppearance = .titles

    //colors
    tabBar?.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
    tabBar?.selectedItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    tabBar?.unselectedItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    tabBar?.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.33, blue:0.59, alpha:1.0)

    tabBar?.selectedItem = tabBar?.items.first
}
```

I noted that on the documentation for MDCTabBarViewController it will create a bottom-anchored tab bar, but how does one use it in the way they clearly illustrate on the 'Tabs' components example where the tabs are located at the top?

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: There's a ticket about this problem that they still not resolve yet: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/6929